# alias/symlink in i18n translation yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml

Suppose I have an i18n locale file defining translation of two models with has_one/belongs_to relationship:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      photo: 'Photo'
      photographer: 'Photographer'
    attributes:
      photo:
        name: 'Name'
        description: 'Description'
        photographer: 'Photographer'
```

As you can see, photographer is defined twice in the file. Is there any way of simplifying this by making an alias or referencing it to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [YAML's anchors and aliases](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395) to accomplish what you want to do.  For example:

```
en:
  photographer: &photographer 'Photographer' 
  activerecord:
    models:
      photo: 'Photo'
      photographer: *photographer
    attributes:
      photo:
        name: 'Name'
        description: 'Description'
        photographer: *photographer
```

However, just before you head down that path, have a read of [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11097572/567863) first and then make up your mind.