# Rails I18n - Translate the same attributes multiple times for model and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Suppose we have a `Book` model with *index*, *show*, *edit* and *new* views. Suppose we want to internationalize and translate all of those views and use lazy lookup (automatic translation scoping) when passing the key names to the `t` method in the views.

The only solution I have found so far is to include multiple keys for the same attribute in the dictionary (YML file): one key for the model (which will translate the form labels) and one additional key for each view. Example:

```
#pt-BR.yml
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      book:
        title: Título
  books:
    index:
      title: Título
    show:
      title: Título
```

Given the importance attributed to the DRY principle in the Rails community, I believe there is probably a way to avoid having multiple keys for the same attribute.

One possible alternative could be to include only the `activerecord` keys in the dictionary (only translate the model) but it seems like lazy lookup will not work in the views. We could do something like `<%= t('activerecord.attributes.book.title') %>` in the views, but it does not look like a proper solution as we have to repeat the entire scope (`activerecord.attributes.book`) every time we call the `t` method.

I appreciate if anyone can point me to a way to better/DRYer way to to this. Thank you.

Comment: First create directory structure for views, controllers & models! And follow this documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I already have the views, controllers, and models in the default Rails directory structure. Also, I have read the Rails Guide on I18n but could not find the answer to this question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097572/refactoring-ruby-on-rails-i18n-yaml-files-using-dictionaries) which contains a lot of relevant information.