# Multi language with Rails app to prepare YML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize

I am building a car rental app with Ruby on Rails and currently I have been coding with English. Basically I have an user and car model, where user can login, sign in, log out and list their car.

I would like to implement another language allowing the user to select English or Spanish from a dropdown. I have default error messages returns from the controller actions such as "can't be blank, already used" etc. And I also have custom JS messages, such as if user successfully adds a car, jQuery returns "your car has been published". Lastly, I also have Flash messages. But I do not know how should I handle errors, custom JS and Flash messages in the YML file according to user's language selection.

Answer (score 0):

It actually really depends on the structure of your YAML file, for example, for `ActiveRecord` error messages:

```
it:
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

    messages: &errors_messages
      empty: "non può essere vuoto"
      blank: "non può essere lasciato in bianco"
```

If you want to access I18n (a.k.a Internationalization) outside of views, you can use `I18n.t(your_key)`, which is in fact the helper you have access to in your views. So for example, if you wish to translate a notice in a controller you could be doing something like:

```
def your_action
  redirect_to other_path, notice: I18n.t("notices.successful_action")
end
```

And then having in your YAML the correspondent structure:

```
en:
  notices:
    successful_action: "You did it!"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how should I handle error, custom js and flash messages in yml file according to user's language selection

- For Rails app-related translations in general, including error messages, the [Rails i18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) has you covered.  You can see what languages have been translated in [the gem's locale file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale).
- For specifically overriding error messages or creating new ones, see The Rails Guide sections on [looking up translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) and [translations for ActiveRecord models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) to see what keys in your YAML files you should be putting your translations under.
- For flash messages, have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22467734/567863) to see how you can use lazy lookups (eg `t('.notice')`) in your controllers.
- For the ability to use translations in Javascript files in the same way you do in Ruby (eg `I18n.t("my_translation")`, and be able to manage those translations in your YAML files with the rest of your Rails translations, have a look at the [i18n-js gem](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js).  Setup instructions are in the README file.