# Rails I18n translations scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, erb, rails-i18n

Writing a fully translated app can become tedious. Is there a way to set a default translation scope for the current context ?

Example : I am writing inside a partial *_deadlines.html.erb* in the *show.html.erb* action of my `ProjectsController`

Now because I am trying to be a good programmer, I am scoping all my translations. I would like to produce the following tree

```
projects:
  deadlines:
    now: "Hurry the deadline is today !"
    ....
```

How can I make it less tedious than writing each time the full scope ?

*projects/show.html.erb*

```
...
<%= render 'projects/deadlines', project: @project %>
...
```

*projects/_deadlines.html.erb* called from *show.html.erb*

```
<p>Deadline : <%= t(:now, scope: [:projects, :deadlines]) %></p>
```

Is there a way to set a default scope for the current context (here the whole *_deadlines.html.erb* file) ?

**EDIT**

Some people suggested to use Rails [Lazy lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup), but this does not produce the scoping I'm looking for. In my case, I want to skip the `action` default scope (show, index, etc...) and add a scope for the current partial I am rendering (in my case _deadlines.html.erb)

Rails lazy lookup :

```
t('.now')
<=> t(:now, scope: [:projects, :show]
```

But I wanted :

```
t('.now')
<=> t(:now, scope: [:projects, :deadlines]
```

Comment: This question is 5 years old. I would not recommend anymore "smart" translation scoping, but just to fall back to the recommended way (based on file path, compatible with Lazy lookup). When your application becomes bigger, it becomes harder to maintain "smart scopes" since it's harder to understand which translations are used where with static analysis.

-> Better to make it easier to know which translations are used where. And if we need to change some key vocabulary, then it's up to the team to go through every available translation, using for example CTRL+F, to change everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I was actuall still not happy with this. This default 'lazy lookup' scope is totally krap when you want to translate the same thing at different places. Say I have two different partials that contain information dealing with the same model. Using lazy lookup, I would need to have the same translation twice in my yml file.

Here's a little piece of code that you can put in your application helper. It's basically an override of the default I18n.t that will set the scope to `@t_scope` when it is defined, and you don't need to worry about the scope anymore

**My code addition**

*helpers/application_helper.rb*

```
def t(*args)
  # If there is just one param and we have defined a translation scope in the view
  # only using symbols right now, need extended version to handle strings
  if args.size == 1 and args.first.is_a?(Symbol) and @t_scope
    super(args.shift, @t_scope)
  else
    super(*args)
  end
end

def set_t_scope(scope)
  push_t_scope(@t_scope ||= {})
  replace_t_scope(scope)
end
alias :t_scope :set_t_scope

def replace_t_scope(scope)
  @t_scope = {scope: scope}
end

def push_t_scope(scope)
  (@tscope_stack ||= []) << scope
end

def pop_t_scope
  @t_scope = @tscope_stack.pop
end
```

**What you can do with it**

*projects/show.html.erb*

```
<%= t_scope([:projects, :deadlines]) %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Deadlines</legend>
  <% if Time.now > @project.deadline.expected_finish_date %>
  <p><%= t(:hurry) %></p>
  <% else %>
  <p><%= t(:you_have_time) %>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Deadlines</legend>
  <%= render 'tasks', tasks: @project.tasks %>
...
```

*views/projects/_tasks.html.erb*

```
<%= t_scope([:projects, :tasks]) %>
  <% tasks.each do | task| %>
  <h2><%= t(:person_in_charge) %></h2>
  ...
<% pop_t_scope %>
```

*en.yml*

```
en:
  projects:
    deadlines:
      hurry: "Hurry man !"
      you_have_time: "Relax, there's still time"
    tasks:
      person_in_charge: 'The Boss is %{name}'
```

Now the only problem that I see, is that when rendering multiple partials from a view, the @t_scope will be transferred and could potentiall cause problems. However wouldn't be a problem is @t_scope is set to nil at the beginning of each file

Comment: I have further refined the code. Contact me if interested.

Comment: This is a great solution EXCEPT it doesnt account for accessing other keys, such as t('footer.about').  It works well with t(:something) so you need to take into account strings versus symbols.  Here is a suggested rewrite: 

https://gist.github.com/noctivityinc/5d4358b560fb92a1af70

Answer (score 5):

Rails implements a convenient way to look up the locale inside views.
When you have the following dictionary:

```
es:
  projects:
    index:  # in 'index.html.erb' template file
      title: "Título"
    deadlines:  # in '_deadlines.html.erb' partial file
      title: "Fecha límite"
```

you can look up these values as below:

```
# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<%= t '.title' %>  # => "Título"

# app/views/projects/_deadlines.html.erb
<%= t '.title' %>  # => "Fecha límite"
```

Comment: Someone else posted almost the same thing, but must have deleted his answer... The fact is that I'm looking for a way to declare a default scope different than the default `controller/action`. Here `t('.title')` would not output `scope: [:projects, :deadlines]`, but rather `scope: [:projects, :index]` as you wrote at the beginning

Comment: Although I might be not understanding your question, I edited. I think lazy lookup is connected with `controller/action`. It's connected with **views** such as `views/projects/_deadlines.html.erb`. So, I think you don't need change scope for `_deadlines.html.erb`. I don't mind you'll delete my post if it's not correct answer.

Comment: Oh right, it actually produces the right output ! sorry

Comment: While your solution is nice, it won't let me have different default scopes per partial, and I cannot map different pages to the same default scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since `t('.foo')` is possible and might have options (for interpolation for example), here is my proposition to improve [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30288684/2616474)

```rb
def t(*args, **kwargs)
  if args.size == 1 and (args.first.is_a?(Symbol) || args.first.to_s.start_with?('.') ) and @t_scope
    I18n.t(args.shift, kwargs.reverse_merge!(@t_scope))
  else
    I18n.t(*args)
  end
end
```