# Rails I18n: avoid key collision between global translations and view namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

Let `offers` be a folder in `app/views`. The locale is:

```
en:
  offers:
    index:
      ...
    new:
      ...
```

i.e. I follow the **Rails convention** so that I can use `t('.something')` in views.

The problem is that I store global translations like this:

```
en:
  a_global_key: A Global Translation
```

So when I want to translate `offers` I would like to add:

```
en:
  offers: Offers
```

But this generates a collision with the previously defined view namespace.

I know I can avoid this by simply using a namespace like `global`for global translations. Then I would always have to write `t(global.a_global_key)` instead of the more concise `t('a_global_key)`.

**Is there a *Rails way* to structure locales that prevents collision between global translations and view namespaces?**

It would be great to be able to write something like the following *invalid YAML*:

```
en:
  offers: Offers
    index:
      ...
    new:
      ...
```

Comment: There's an argument to be made for using an explicit namespaced i18n architecture, rather than a cryptic one. This post's most popular answer describes a i18n architecture that is logical and maintainable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282857/how-do-you-structure-i18n-yaml-files-in-rails?rq=1